# Is it possible to strip or completely remove UIImageOrientation information from a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

Is it possible to strip or completely remove `UIImageOrientation` information from a UIImage?

Can I set `image.imageOrientation = nil` or to nothing?

I want to physically rotate my image and strip the orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not set to nil the imageOrientation since it's not an object. You could find it in the UIImage header definition file and you'll find it's defined as a NSInteger

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIImageOrientation)
```

Apart from being a NSInteger the property associate to it is readonly, which means you can not change it directly through setter method:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIImageOrientation imageOrientation;
```

***UIImageOrientationUp*** is the default orientation for UIImage, what you could do is to create a new image with the orientation you want to use/prefer using for example:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)cgImage scale:(CGFloat)scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);
```